# Чтение побайтно и построчно из InputStream

Tags: java, строки

Добрый день!
Есть некий набор данных:

> ```
> string1  
> string2  
> string3  
> stringN(какое-то неизвестное количество строк)  
> stringFlag(строка, которая указывает, что следующая строка - набор байт)
> [массив байт]  
> stringFlag2(строка, которая указывает, что набор байт кончился)
> stringN(какое-то неизвестное количество строк)
> ```

Собственно, чтение построчно - не проблема, чтение побайтово - не проблема.

Задача в том, что бы считывать строки построчно и заносить в память, а вот массив байт записывать на диск, не сохраняя в память(т.к. он может быть > 100MB).

Проблема: как определить, что массив байт уже кончился? Следующую строку необходимо тоже внести в память полностью, что бы кусок её не остался в массиве.

Каждая строка разделена символами "\r\n"

Цель на максимальную оптимизацию.
upd. Есть общее количество байт в переменной dataLength;

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html может это

Comment: Он читает построчно и посимвольно, нужно побайтово.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html тогда

Comment: мне неудобно вам это говорить, но вы читали мой вопрос? Я знаю, как прочесть массив байт. Я не знаю, как из 100 строк прочесть одну побайтово, не сохраняя ее в памяти.

Comment: > Я не знаю, как из 100 строк прочесть одну побайтово, не сохраняя ее в памяти.

@Mihail  Petelin, поясните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду под "прочесть, не сохраняя в памяти".

FYI, в целях поддержания хорошей производительности большие объемы обычно читают именно массивами, а не побайтово.

Comment: Вроде так:    
>    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./12.txt");  
>    while(string_Is_Not_End) {  
>        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*10];  
>        getInputStream.read(buffer);  
>        out.write(buffer);  
>    }  
>    out.close();
Имелась ввиду работа с маленькими фрагментами, а не 100мб сразу.

Comment: а как вы узнаете какого размера массива? по завершаемому "\r\n"? А в середине произвольного массива эти символы не могу встретится?

Comment: Именно в этом и проблема.

Comment: А, ну тогда никак =)

Comment: @IronVbif так ведь в конце ещё `stringFlag2` будет, а он в середине сам по себе не встретится.

Comment: @Mihail  Petelin, читайте кусками, как читаете, только добавьте проверку на наличие `stringFlag2`. А всё что после приклеивайте к следующей строке.

Comment: Лучше после маркера начала данных — `stringFlag` —  отправлять количество байт данных, чтобы знать, сколько нужно прочитать, нежели читать до ожидаемого `stringFlag2`.

Что до самого вопроса, автору, скорее всего, нужен аналог TFileStream (вероятно, это [FileOutputStream](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=FileOutputStream+java))

Comment: @Jofsey В произвольном массиве байтов может встретиться любая последовательность символов, поэтому найти stringFlag2 там можно. Если это действительно raw bytes, то конец не найти. Если stringFlag2 заэкранирован в массиве, или байты хранятся в текстовой кодировке типа Base64 или hex - то можно.